# Delete all files from a directory except for folder and it's contents

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6, compact-framework2.0

I am trying to remove all files on my storage card without removing one. I can keep the directory I specify but not its contents with my current code. It just leaves the blank 
folder data because it removes everything inside. How can I keep it from removing that folder and its contents?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScanDirectory scanDirectory = new ScanDirectory();
   scanDirectory.WalkDirectory(@"/Storage Card");
   scanDirectory.WalkDirectory(@"/Application");
}

public class ScanDirectory
{
   public void WalkDirectory(string directory)
   {
      WalkDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(directory));
   }

   private static void WalkDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
   {
      // Scan all files in the current path
      foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
      {
         file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

         var name = file.Name;
         name = name.ToLower();
         if (name != "test.txt")
         {
            file.Delete();
         }
      }
      DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
      foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subDirectories)
      {
         WalkDirectory(subDirectory);
         subDirectory.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

         var name = subDirectory.Name;
         name = name.ToLower();
         if (name != "data")
         {
            subDirectory.Delete();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how with your current code that it could successfully delete a file named `test.txt`.  If you write to the console each file you traverse, does that file really come up?

Comment: it works fine. I will not delete text.txt or folder called data, just confirmed

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what the 'name' variable is.

Comment: I am a bit confused - what folder are you trying to keep?  Based on your code you are saying that any file named test.txt will not be deleted as well as any folder under the top level named data (as long as the directory is empty).

Comment: That is just about correct. I am trying to keep the top level data folder and it's contents. So far it is removing it with it's contents.
It keeps the data folder and removes everything inside.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way in which the recursive function calls are done: the main function `private static void WalkDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)` deletes all files and is called every time (even while analysing a subdirectory). Here you have a fix to make this code work as you wish:

```
   private static void WalkDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
   {
       if (directory.Name.ToLower() != "data")
       {
         // Scan all files in the current path
         foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
         {
             file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

             var name = file.Name;
             name = name.ToLower();
             if (name != "test.txt")
             {
               file.Delete();
             }
         }

         DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
         foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subDirectories)
         {
            WalkDirectory(subDirectory);
            subDirectory.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            var name = subDirectory.Name;
            name = name.ToLower();
            if (name != "data")
            {
               subDirectory.Delete();
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Could you assist once more in the proper way of calling it? If not i will figure it out eventually.

Comment: This correction is precisely to make it work as so far (just replace the function and let the rest of the code as it is). When you call a function recursively, you have to make sure that it accounts for all the possible scenarios. Here you have two possble scenarios: main directory and subdirectory; but your original function was just accounting for the main scenario (= deleting all the files and all the subdirectories). Thus, more than calling it rightly is preparing it properly to deal with everything it has to deal with (or use different functions).

Comment: No problem. If your code is now working, please, mark this answer as the right one.

Comment: Ok new issue, how can i keep it from deleting any subfolders also in the data folder? it doesn't delete files inside the data folder but does delete subfolders?

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that. I updated my answer. This will work unless the main direction is called "data". If you want to account for any situation (even for cases where the main directory is called "data"), you would have to change the function and include a further parameter to tell whether this is the first iteration (upper level) or not.

Comment: But well... the point here is not delivering working codes, but helping to understand where the problem is located (to learn, grow as a developer, etc.). Have you got the idea or shall I explain it better to you?

Comment: awesome, i think that did it. varocarbas you are the man.. thankyou sir.

Comment: I don't think that this answer makes me awesome, but thanks. Let's close this question, then.

Comment: varocarbos, so I don't need  public void WalkDirectory(string directory)
    {
        WalkDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(directory));
    } anymore?

Comment: I think that this has got for long enough. You have pretty clear ideas regarding all what you did wrong to create a new proper code by your own. If you prefer to use my solution, you should read it, understand it and thus know how to use it. In any case, I have explained it to you various times: I have just edited your function (= everything works as in your original code: replace your function with mine and let the rest as it was). If you want to close this question and check this as the right answer, do it. I will not continue answering question because I don't see the point.

Comment: i really am sorry, I moved around a file in my cab file that led me to believe it was not working again. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void WalkDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
   {
       if (directory.Name.ToLower() != "data")
       {
         // Scan all files in the current path
         foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
         {
             file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

             var name = file.Name;
             name = name.ToLower();
             if (name != "test.txt")
             {
               file.Delete();
             }
         }

         DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
         foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subDirectories)
         {
            WalkDirectory(subDirectory);
            subDirectory.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            var name = subDirectory.Name;
            name = name.ToLower();
            if (name != "data")
            {
               subDirectory.Delete();
            }
         }
      }
   }
```